# google map api，chrome and firefox is right，but ie can't run

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, internet-explorer-6

google map api，chrome and firefox is right，but ie can't run
I use jquery load initialize();

ie6 outpute error message is
error 'google' undefine

```
function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(39.979639,116.30209);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    myOptions);

}

$(document).ready(function(){
    initialize();
});
```

Comment: Show us how you're calling in the Google API JS files, and in relation to where you call the initialize() function.

Answer (score 0):

You’re not actually calling the map initialisation function. You’d need to do something like:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
```

But of course without that it wouldn’t work anything else either… Is the version of IE you’re testing in IE6? It’s not officially supported by Google Maps anymore.

Comment: That should work as it’s straight from the developers guide. If it doesn’t, and you’re using a supported version of IE (7+) then I’d try removing other JS to see if that’s breaking IE before it gets to the map code. Maybe look for trailing commas in objects? They work in other browsers but not in IE7 or 8. E.g. `{ foo: 'bar', qux: 'quux', }` won’t work in IE.

Comment: Ah, in that case have a look at their FAQs. IE6 isn’t supported with the v3 API. If you need IE6 support you’ll need to use v2, but I’d recommend against it as you lose a bunch of iPad etc compatibility. https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#browsersupport

Comment: As a side note, you might want accept answers if they’ve helped out. People are more likely to help if you have a history of acceptance, as that builds their reputation.

Comment: @Robin: Version 2 maps work on the iPad, including stretch/pinch to zoom and draggable markers. But it will only last until May 2013, so it's definitely not a permanent solution.

Comment: Oh, OK. I thought that was one of the big benefits of v3? Glad to be corrected though, as I had to build a v2 map late last year as v3 hadn’t (at that point) carried over the editable polygon functionality.

Comment: Ah, well: I haven't used editable polygons on an iPad. But they may work. I was surprised at how well zooming and draggable markers worked. I'd go so far as to say that most Version 2 functionality will work.